# Upload DocuSign Brand Profiles

Tags: php, docusignapi

What is the structure and contents of the .ZIP that needs to be uploaded to DocuSign using the REST API for uploading a new brand profile?

The online documentation is pretty sparse:
https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Upload%20Brand%20Profiles.htm

```
POST https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/brands

X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/zip

<base64bytes brand zip file removed for brevity>
```

When I send (PHP+cURL) a zip archive of the the exported master resource files, it succeeds but creates three random imported brands:

```
branding.zip
  |__ DocuSign_EmailResources.xml
  |__ DocuSign_SendResources.xml
  |__ DocuSign_SignResources.xml
```

I've also attempted exporting a previously created branding in the DocuSign developer console (truncated example below):

```
<Brand><BrandId>ce173f6e-3549-4494-a8ea-f8f33a0dba64</BrandId><BrandName>ExampleBrand</BrandName><CompanyName>Example Co. Ltd</CompanyName><BackgroundColor>#F3F3F3</BackgroundColor><BackgroundTextColor>#FFFFFF</BackgroundTextColor> [TRUNCATED]
```

The complete Brand XML is available here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/022b3d1491a27e75f3ac

Then created the archive from that single XML file.

```
branding.zip
  |__ Brand_ExampleBrand.xml
```

When uploading it with the API it results in this error:

```
BRAND_CREATE_FAILED: Brands could not be created. Unable to upload brand Brand_ExampleBrand.xml, error: Could not find any recognizable digits.
```

What is the correct way to use this endpoint?

Comment: I see you mention that when you send PHP request it succeeds but creates 3 separated brand profiles.  This is by design as you are allowed to custom brand the Email resources, the sending experience, and the signing experience.  So I'm wondering, when that call succeeds what are you expecting to have happen that does not?

Comment: Interesting, I'm actually seeing some different results when I test this.  I download a brand XML from my account, then zip it and supply it in a POST request to the `/accounts/{accountId}/brands` URI (I'm NOT base64 encoding it) and I get a 400 BRAND_CREATE_FAILED returned, HOWEVER my brand still gets successfully added to the account.  I've gone ahead and logged a bug for this...

Comment: @Ergin, I guess I'm expecting that when I `POST` the compressed `Brand_ExampleBrand.xml` to `/accounts/{accountId}/brands` it should create a single new entry in 'Preferences' > 'Branding' in the DocuSign developer console with all my customisations.

Comment: I just noticed you are sending a zip archive of the the exported master resource file.  For my tests, which result in a new brand profile showing up on my branding page, I am first going to that page and using the `Export` button on one of my brands.  That creates the XML that I then zip and upload through the API.  Can you confirm you've tested this?..

Comment: That is the second archive I've tried above. I used a zip archive of the exported branding XML but this returned the error `BRAND_CREATE_FAILED: Brands could not be created. Unable to upload brand Brand_ExampleBrand.xml, error: Could not find any recognizable digits` . That suggests it managed to unpack the archive but found the contained exported brand XML file invalid.

Comment: Can you post your brand XML?

Comment: @Ergin See here for the full brand XML: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/022b3d1491a27e75f3ac

Comment: That's so weird, using your un-edited XML I zipped it up and tried uploading and I see the same results as I reported earlier - I get the 400 `BRAND_CREATE_FAILED` however it still creates the brand profile in my account and I see all of the settings that are in the XML.  The error message I get is different than yours, I get `Brands could not be created. Unable to upload brand __MACOSX/, error: Root element is missing.\r\nUnable to upload brand __MACOSX/._TEST.xml, error: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.`

Comment: But as mentioned it still uploads (this was with no other brands in my account).  Are you still base64 encoding your XML or just sending the zip?

Comment: I just zip the XML file and send that. Should I be sending a base64 encoded string of the XML file instead?